# Initialising std::array from pointer into a buffer elegantly?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

What is the 'proper' way in C++11 and beyond to initialise a `std::array` from a pointer into a buffer?

I currently have

```
using guid_t = std::array<uint8_t, 16>;

inline guid_t make_guid(const uint8_t * bytes)
{
    guid_t res;
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
    {
        res[i] = bytes[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

in my code but this just appears sloppy and inefficient - it seems like this should be a one liner using something in the standard libraries however I can't find it anywhere via searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a handful of options, assuming that bytes always have at least size valid elements.

```
std::copy_n(bytes, res.size(), res.begin());
```

or

```
std::copy(bytes, bytes+res.size(), res.begin());
```

You could also use `std::memcpy`, but I prefer the above two, as they work with non-byte data as well.

Comment: thanks, so I'm not wrong then that there is no way to do it within the constructor of res?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::copy(bytes, bytes + guid.size(), guid.begin());
```

That being said, it's not like this is more efficient - it's slightly more compact, really mostly a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I propose the following solution based on uniform initialization and variadic templates.

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
inline guid_t make_guid_h (uint8_t const * bytes,
                           std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return { { bytes[Is] ... } }; }

inline guid_t make_guid (uint8_t const * bytes)
 { return make_guid_h(bytes,
      std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<guid_t>::value>{}); }
```

Unfortunately use `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`, that are available only from C++14, but it's easy develop a substitute for C++11.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using guid_t = std::array<uint8_t, 16>;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
inline guid_t make_guid_h (uint8_t const * bytes,
                           std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return { { bytes[Is] ... } }; }

inline guid_t make_guid (uint8_t const * bytes)
 { return make_guid_h(bytes,
      std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<guid_t>::value>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   uint8_t foo []
      = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53 };

   auto bar = make_guid(foo);

   for ( auto const & ui : bar )
      std::cout << int(ui) << ", ";

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for playing :) +1 for effort ... sort of seems like a case of the space pen vs the pencil.

Comment: I found this approach appealing that it can be  `constexpr`-ified, and can thereby be used in a `constexpr` function, which cannot be achieved with `std::copy`.